# Web scraping on Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, user-agent, pythonanywhere

In my project I scraping data from Amazon. I deploy this on Pythonanywhere(I'm using paid account). But there is a problem that the code (I'm using BeautifulSoup4) doesn't get the html of the site when I try it on Pythonanywhere. It gets the Something Went Wrong site of Amazon. But on my local it works perfectly. I think its about User Agents. On my local I use my own User Agent. When deploying which User Agent should I use? And how can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
            URL = link    ##some amazon link
            headers = {"User-Agent": " ##my user agent"}

            page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
            soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(soup1.prettify(), "html.parser")
```

Is there any way I can do it on Pythonanywhere?

Comment: Use the same user agent as locally. And it is perfectly possible that Amazon simply blocks *any* / all requests from pythonanywhere.

Comment: @luk2302 When I use the same user agent it still doesn't get the actual page

Comment: As @luk2302 mentioned, it's very likely Amazon has PythonAnywhere's IP range blocked. Use of these types of scripts is indubitably against Amazon's [Conditions of Use](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=GLSBYFE9MGKKQXXM): "*This license [to use Amazon] does not include... any use of data mining, robots, or similar data gathering and extraction tools.*" You should make use of the SSH access granted to you via your paid account and run rudimentary connection checks (`traceroute`, `telnet`, `wget`, etc.) to ensure this is the case.

Comment: @esqew Under certain circumstances, in certain jurisdictions, the limited right to scrape is protected by law. Doesn't mean Amazon will co-operate, though.

Answer (score 5):

Your code works perfectly on my home machine, so the issue could be:

- PythonAnywhere machine's IP being blocked by Amazon (as others have mentioned)
- Another issue with the machine's access to the internet (Try scraping another site to test this)

To solve the former, you'd probably want to try out a proxy connection to change the IP you access Amazon with (I suggest you check PythonAnywhere's and Amazon's Terms of Service to be aware of any risks). The usage would look something like this:

```
import requests
proxies = { 
    "http": "http://IP:Port", # HTTP
    "https": "https://IP:Port", # HTTPS
    'http': 'socks5://user:pass@IP:Port' # SOCKS5
}
URL = "https://api4.my-ip.io/ip" # Plaintext IPv4 to test
page = requests.get(URL, proxies=proxies)
print(page.text)
```

Finding proxies to use takes a couple Google searches, but the difficult part is swapping them out occasionally since they don't last forever.

Comment: This answer is actually fully addressing the question, as it was asked. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Try Selenium Webdriver instead of BeautifulSoup4. I had this issue myself when deploying a web scraper to pythonanywhere.com

pythonanywhere.com require a Hacker plan (as a minimum) to run web scraping applications. I was told this by their support team: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/pricing/

I also used the following user-agent and chrome options:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
```

As per: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/21948/

Comment: What was the issue?  What kind of error message did you get?  Is [this](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium/) code working for you?